# How to set the height of prototype cells in an iOS table views

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a table view with a prototype cell containing both disclosure and detail accessories. I want to use a font size of 12 in the cell and reduce the row height accordingly. Thus the size of the two accessory icons need to be reduced in size as well. I assumed this would be one of the more obvious things one might want to do with a table view but fail miserably in figuring out how?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are have a nib or storyboard, you should see a resize handle on the cells when you select a cell in the editor.  Just grab and resize.